# Using DynamoDBMarshaller - how marshall can return int

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to get for dynamoDB table and i am getting error:

```
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: 
Expected S in value {N: 0,} when invoking public void 
com.genieo.installer.data.MacClient.setGuardActivityCounter(int)"]}
```

I understood that I need to use DynamoDBMarshaller implementation.

I tried it like this:

```
public static class GuardActivityCounterDynamoDBMarshaller implements DynamoDBMarshaller<Integer>
{

    @Override
    public int marshall(Integer getterReturnResult) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer unmarshall(Class<Integer> clazz, String obj) {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

but unfortunately the  marshall function can not return int.

I would love if someone could  help me please.

Thanks in advance

Gal

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you have stored an attribute on DynamoDB with String data type. However, when you return the value from mapper, you would like to return it as integer (i.e. Java primitive int type).

Here is the example.

Please note that the attribute is defined as **`int`** on model.

```
private int postCounter;

@DynamoDBTyped(DynamoDBAttributeType.S)
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "postCounter")
public int getPostCounter() {
    return postCounter;
}
```

**postCounter attribute is stored as String in DynamoDB table:-**

See the screenshot below.

However, the mapper treats the attribute as Integer. The annotation **`@DynamoDBTyped`** is used to indicate the DynamoDB data type rather than interpreting automatically based on Java data type.

[image]